# Why can't use C standard I/O with sockets

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming

It's often said that one shouldn't use C standard I/O functions (like `fprintf()`, `fscanf()`) when working with sockets.

I can't understand why. I think if the reason was just in their buffered nature, one could just flush the output buffer each time he outputs, right?

Why everyone uses UNIX I/O functions instead? Are there any situations when the use of standard C functions is appropriate and correct?

Comment: that's news to me.  `stdio` is just a buffered wrapped around plain file descriptors, so IMHO there's no reason not to.

Comment: Aside from the answers given, there can also be issues with closing down.  `fclose()` will call `close()` to close the fd, but the differences between `shutdown()` and `close()` are significant.  A file descriptor may be duplicated, and `close()` does not disconnect until the last file descriptor is closed, whereas `shutdown()` deactivates the socket at once.  In addition, using the How flags, we can shutdown in just one direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can certainly use `stdio` with sockets. You can even write a program that uses nothing but `stdin` and `stdout`, run it from `inetd` (which provides a socket on `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO`), and it works even though it doesn't contain any socket code at all.

What you can't do is mix buffered I/O with `select` or `poll` because there is no `fselect` or `fpoll` working on `FILE *`'s and you can't even implement one yourself because there's no standard way of querying a `FILE *` to find out whether its input buffer is empty.

As soon as you need to handle multiple connections, `stdio` is not good enough.

Comment: We can use `int fileno(FILE *stream)` to obtain a file descriptor that corresponds to `FILE *` variable, can't we?

Comment: @MaximSkurydin yes, but it has it's costs.

Comment: @MaximSkurydin You can get the fd and pass it to select, but the select blocks because it thinks there's nothing available to read, because the data you haven't read yet is in the stdio buffer which select doesn't know about.

Comment: stdio is good enough for multiple connections if you use multiple threads.

Answer (score 3):

It's totally fine when you have simple scenario with one socket in blocking mode and your application protocol is text-based.

It quickly becomes a huge pain with more then one or non-blocking socket(s), with any sort of binary encoding, and with any real performance requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Do not know any direct objection. Most likely this will work fine.

At the same time I can imagine that a platform, where `fprintf()` and `fscanf()` have their own buffers, staying above the file descriptor layer. You may not be able to flush these buffers.

It is hard to speak about all possible platforms. This means that it is better to avoid this with sockets.

At the end of the day the app program should solve the app problem. It should not be a compiler/library test.

Answer (score 0):

It's because sockets (TCP sockets, for example) are readable and writable as if they were files or pipes, but this is just an abstraction. The inner workings of a network connection are much more complicated than a local file or pipe.

To start with, reading a file is always "fast", either you get the data or bump end-of-file. In the other hand, if you expect 500 bytes from a TCP connection and it sends 499 (and the connection is not closed), you may be waiting forever. Writing is the same thing: it will block after TCP output buffer.

Even the most basic program needs to handle timeouts, disconnection, and all these things interact with FILE's own buffered I/O, not even textbook examples could be expected to work well.

Answer (score 0):

From the man pages of `fdopen`:

> Reads  and  writes  may be intermixed on read/write streams in any order.  Note that ANSI C requires that a file positioning function intervene between output and input, unless an input operation encounters end-of-file.

In practice, this means that when using standard I/O functions, we need to call `fseek` between read and write operations (for synchronization).

The problem is that socket files are not seekable (There are some workarounds  but they is not a complete and clean solution to this, specifically fflush does not work for *output functions following input functions*).

Also as mentioned in the accepted answer: `FILE` streams doesn't work well in IO multiplexing file descriptors with `epoll`/`poll`/`select` (notice that concurrency may be achieved with threads, and in this case you may use functions from `stdio` as they are thread-safe).

Thus it is generally recommended not to use the standard I/O functions for input and output on network sockets.